# how to match /data1 as word with the help of grep

Tags: shell, solaris-10

I am using **Solaris 5.10** and working on **Bash Shell**. I have a shell script in which the following statement not working

```
ssh 172.18.16.55 "df -h" |grep -w /data1
```

When I replace **/data1** with **data1** (i.e removed "/"), it is working correctly.

I have another statement like below which is working fine.

```
ssh 172.18.16.55 "df -h" |grep -w /dev/dsk/c1t0d0s0
```

According to my understanding, first occurrence of "/" (forward slash) is not getting recognized by the shell script. I want to know what is the significance of "/" in shell script?
below are my outputs.

```
root@P020XIDCNF # ssh 172.18.16.55 "df -h" |grep '/data1\>'
/dev/md/dsk/d50         84G    59G    24G    71%    /data1
```

---

```
root@P020XIDCNF # ssh 172.18.16.55 "df -h" |grep -w /data1
```

does not print anything.

---

```
root@P020XIDCNF # ssh 172.18.16.55 "df -h" |grep /data1
/dev/md/dsk/d50         84G    59G    24G    71%    /data1
```

Comment: Define "not working". What's the expected output, and what's the actual output?

Comment: grep not returning anything even though it has **/data1**  .it should return mountpoint containing  named /data1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep`'s `-w` option tells to match the pattern as a "word", i.e., with a "word boundary" before and after it.  I think what's happening is that grep's idea of a word boundary doesn't match what you're expecting.

You can use `\<` and `\>` to match word boundaries explicitly.

Here are some examples run on a Solaris 9 system:

```
% echo /dev/md/dsk/d50 84G 59G 25G 71% /data1 | grep -w /data1
% echo /dev/md/dsk/d50 84G 59G 25G 71% /data1 | grep '\</data1\>'
% echo /dev/md/dsk/d50 84G 59G 25G 71% /data1 | grep '/data1\>'  
/dev/md/dsk/d50 84G 59G 25G 71% /data1
%
```

Apparently Solaris `grep` doesn't consider the the boundary between a space and a `/` character to be a word boundary.

I suggest running `man grep`, and probably following some of the "See also" references, to see just how this is documented.  (I tried to do that myself, but the Solaris system I have access to is having problems at the moment.)

If you want to use this command as part of a reasonably portable script, you need to be aware that this is an area where GNU `grep` behaves differently.  I get the following on my Linux system with GNU `grep`:

```
% echo /dev/md/dsk/d50 84G 59G 25G 71% /data1 | grep -w /data1
/dev/md/dsk/d50 84G 59G 25G 71% /data1
% echo /dev/md/dsk/d50 84G 59G 25G 71% /data1 | grep '\</data1\>'
% echo /dev/md/dsk/d50 84G 59G 25G 71% /data1 | grep '/data1\>'  
/dev/md/dsk/d50 84G 59G 25G 71% /data1
%
```

Note that your question would have been easier to answer if you had shown us the exact line that you expected to be matched.

Comment: this is the line I am trying to match                  **/dev/md/dsk/d50         84G    59G    25G    71%    /data1**

Comment: @Balaswamyvaddeman: That's odd.  I just tried `echo /dev/md/dsk/d50 84G 59G 25G 71% /data1 | grep -w /data1`, and it printed the line.  What happens when you use `grep '/data1\>'` rather than `grep -w /data1`?  What about just `grep /data1`?

Comment: **grep '/data1\>'** prints the line. **grep -w /data1** does not print anything. **grep /data1** prints the line

Comment: @Balaswamyvaddeman: That's difficult to read without proper formatting.  I think I see the output you're getting, but I can't explain it.  Try `ssh 172.18.16.55 "df -h" | grep /data1 | cat -A`, and please show the command and its output in the question, not as a comment.

Comment: @Balaswamyvaddeman: And this probably isn't relevant to your problem, but you shouldn't be doing this kind of thing as `root`.  Use the `root` account *only* for things that actually need root privileges.

Comment: it is part of another shell script which requires root previleges

Comment: @ Keith Thompson echo /dev/md/dsk/d50 84G 59G 25G 71% /data1 | grep -w /data1  does not print anything on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that the output returned by `df -h` actually contains the string `/data1`?  `grep` will not print anything if the string is not found.

**EDIT** In order to make the answer easier to find, his problem was that `grep` did not consider `/data1` a word.

Comment: Try dumping the `-w` flag.  That may be the problem.  If that doesn't work, could you upload the output?

Comment: u r right it is working without -w .just want to know with **-w** option why it is not considering /

Comment: The output could be formated in a way that `/data1` is not considered a word by `grep`.